# Can't download objects from S3 using the URL link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a policy like below which I've attached to several users:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::foo-bar",
                "arn:aws:s3:::foo-bar/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The intent of this policy is that these users would have full control over the bucket `foo-bar`. However, I'm noticing that even though the users can download the objects in these buckets using Accesskey and Secretkey. They can not download the objects via a URL e.g. `https://s3.amazonaws.com/foo-bar/test.docx`

I am currently logged in as a `IAMManager` user and also have `AmazonS3FullAccess`. I can see the list of objects in this bucket but when I click the URL I can't download them. I can, however, download them via clicking the Download button.

**Question**

Is there anything I need to change in my policy OR the objects can *only* be downloaded via the URL when they are publicly available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using your IAM policy on your users, you are granting S3 API access to the bucket for those users only. However, when accessing the bucket via the URL, you are not using the S3 APIs and no authentication information is being sent.

In order to download objects from an S3 bucket directly via the URL, the bucket needs to be made public, which you may or may not want to do.